# Root/tips to make camera app start faster?

Tags: camera

I am specifically concerned with the camera app on my new Nexus 6P. The camera starts slow compared to iPhone cam even though the shot quality is great.

Is there a way to give the camera app more access to RAM so that it can run more smoothly? Or is there any hope for Android to be as smooth as iOS lol?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Camera as Quick access, may be the camera widget can work for your problem.

Take a look on this pro app - **[InstaCamera Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longwell.instant.camera.pro)**, Works like charm, as you want. It works very fast, with two widget you can operate it very well.

Features Included from the Play Store:

- Choose the folder your photos get saved in
- Take multiple shots in a row (up to five)
- Mute the shutter sound
- Turn the "Image Saved" confirmation off
- Change the photo resolution (default is max)
- Set the focus mode (including fixed, infinite, auto and macro focus modes)
- Set the shutter delay (from not-even-focusing to two seconds) in case your camera hardware needs extra time
- Stay in camera mode after taking instant photos (then you touch the screen to take more, and back button to quit)
- There are two widgets: the 1x1, which is just the camera button, and the 2x1, which has a camera button and a settings button.

**Free Version of InstaCamera App** -  [**InstaCameraApp**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longwell.instant.camera&hl=en)